# Tweepy SaveFile not defined

Tags: python, tweepy

I am a beginner with Python and I am trying to use Tweepy to save some tweets and in doing so I am struggling to write them to a file.

I get the error that saveFile is not defined.

class listener(StreamListener):

```
def on_data(self, data):
    try:
        print data
        safeFile = open('twitDb.csv', 'w')
        saveFile.write (data)
        saveFile.write('\n')
        saveFile.close()
        return True
    except BaseException, e:
        print'failed ondata,',str(e)

def on_error (self, status):
    print status
```

auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['prime'])

My token's seem to be working fine and the tweets do stream in idle. The file appears though there is nothing in there

The error code is

failed ondata, global name 'saveFile' is not defined

It does as mentioned print the data

Comment: how you calling `on_data`?

Comment: Please include the full code and the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error must be because of a typo - note that variable name used here **is not saveFile**.

```
safeFile = open('twitDb.csv', 'w')
```

Also consider that you are opening the file in "w" mode for every tweet - as the code is now you would overwrite the file every time a tweet is received.

A better way to do this is to open the file when initializing the listener (`__init__`), and then write to it from on_data:

```
class listener(StreamListener):
  def __init__(self):
    self.saveFile = open('twitDb.csv', 'w')
```

Do remember to close the file after the work's done.

BTW there is a `csv` module that can help read and write CSV files: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: Please show the full code and full error trackback. (Put in on a service like gist.github.com and include a link in your question - also add an update to your question that the typo is fixed by there are still errors).

Comment: That worked great. Sorry for the silly error. Thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment also, the typo was the error.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO in script, change `safeFile = open('twitDb.csv', 'w')` to `saveFile = open('twitDb.csv', 'w')`.

My suggestion to use is start using IDE or editors which highlight that typos for you, for instance [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/)

Comment: @FreddieButcherd You are welcome ! Have a nice day :)